# .htaccess multiple rewrite rules for codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to ask how can we add an additional rewrite rule(s) in .htaccess file including the index.php removal rule in codeigniter.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ /index.php/front/profileDetail/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

The problem is that, only one of the rule works at a time. If I save the file as shown above it returns internal server error!

What I want is completely remove index.php file plus rewrite the url from  xyz.com/front/profileDetail/50 into xyz.com/profile/50

Please help what's wrong, I am completely newbie in this regard.

Thanks! in advance.

Comment: I would use routes (config/routes.php) for rewriting `xyz.com/front/profileDetail/50` to `xyz.com/profile/50`, not .htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above, in config/routes, you would put:

```
$route['profile/(:num)'] = 'front/profileDetail/$1';
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your recommendation for url rewrite using CI routes is more acceptable to me rather than using .htaccess.

Thanks! again a lot.

Comment: @DipenGrg glad that helped you out. Please accept my answer as "solved" by clicking the checkmark next to it - thx :)