# CodeIgniter and specific rewrite rule

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2, cache-manifest, application-cache

On my CodeIgniter site, I would like to add a specific rewrite rule, so that this url
http://www.exemple.com/cache.manifest

would rewrite to

http://www.exemple.com/controller/manifest

(because Safari 7 seems to only accept .manifest files for ApplicationCache)

So I try to add this line to my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^cache.manifest$ controller/manifest
```

I added it before the other rewrite rules :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cache.manifest$ controller/manifest
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it returns a 404. If I change the line to

```
RewriteRule ^cache.manifest$ test.html
```

it works. So the first part on my rule is correct.

If I try to access directly to www.example.com/controller/manifest, it works to, so my url is correct.

I tried also

```
RewriteRule ^cache.manifest$ index.php/controller/manifest [L]
```

But it doesn't work either…

Any clue ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have your tried: RewriteRule ^cache.manifest$ /index.php/controller/manifest [L] - you may need the / before index.php

Comment: Just to be sure, cache.manifest is a file?

Comment: no, cache.manifest does not exists. But it's the point of a RewriteRule, or I don't understand your question ?

Comment: Following [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278652/htaccess-multiple-rewrite-rules-for-codeigniter?rq=1) in the "Related" section on the right, I discovered the ability to specify rewrite in the config/routes.php file, and it works ! `$route["cache.manifest"] = "controller/manifest";` It doesn't explain why the rewriterule in the htaccess doesn't work, but it's enough for me (although the safari 7 bug remains)

Comment: CodeIgniter's route module is quite useful and powerful.  I posted a Apache solution below that may work, it would be good to know so please try it.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some tests on my local server and I think the following might work:

```
RewriteRule ^cache.manifest$ /index.php/controller/manifest [R,L]
```

I am not entirely sure if you need the leading "/" or "/index.php", so you
may need to experiment.

You need the `[R]` flag to force a redirect.  In this situation, you want Apache
to look for the string `cache.manifest` in the URL, and then go to the CI page
`controller/manifest`.

It appears that you need to explicitly set the redirect.

Please let me know if this works. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I can't add the R tag, because I need the url to remains with a .manifest suffix

Comment: I see, this is a tricky one!  In that case, the CI route module is the way to go.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, Marc ! By the way, it didn't solve my problem, as the Safari bug wasn't related to the manifest name, but to the applicationCache.abort() function… :+/